# 'owner_change' signal of Gtk 2 is not thrown for windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, gtk

We are trying to catch the copy event for clipboard. We are using Gtk 2 with Python 2.7 and have successfully done this with Linux. But for windows 10 `owner_change` signal is not thrown. Below is the simplified version of what we are trying to do:

```
import gtk

def test(*args):
  print "Clipboard changed"

clip = gtk.Clipboard()
clip.connect('owner-change',test)
gtk.main()
```

To check further we tried to print `clip.get_owner()` and it returned `None`